# I would like to warn SO users about how to avoid having their developer certificate revoked

Tags: discussion, scope

I just found out that you can get your Mac Developer certificate revoked when I tried innocently to share an app between two computers I own via a cloud service. What is the recommended approach to warn SO users about this? Ask a question and then answer it myself? Or should I use another Stack Exchange site for that? I would like to do this in order to warn other developers not to fall in this really nasty trap, because once the certificate is revoked all your apps signed with that certificate will crash. I would also like to explain how to get out of this pretty quickly, but you need to know how.

Comment: If you're going to share anything here, it would need to fit into the Q&A format. I think "Why was my developer certificate revoked?" could be a good question, if you included the specific details of the scenario that caused that. If it happens to someone else, your answer could help them understand how to resolve the problem.

Comment: Well, maybe wait for more input here than just mine. I approve of my opinion, but others may offer different viewpoints you'll want to consider.

Comment: I was thinking to ask this question: Why suddenly all my apps did start to crash with an EXC_CRASH (Code Signature Invalid)?

Comment: I'm only a SO user, but I would hope that any Stack Exchange site (sans Meta) would *require* a full answer. Being an Apple developer myself, you haven't given enough details here about *why* your certificate was revoked. In fact, you didn't mention if the party involved (is it Apple or are you part of a third party team that revoked it), any communications (warnings? reasons? was something against your agreement cited?), etc. Truth is, if I saw a question that is self-answered like this on SO (again, not a participant on other sites) I'd flag it for deletion.

Comment: @dfd I made my previous comment assuming that jvarela knew the details you're referring to (since it sounds like the problem is solved at this point) and would provide them in the question+self-answer on main, but that they would be kind of extraneous in this meta question.

Comment: Apple did it. It is apparently a safety measure to avoid malware to be spread via cloud services. I just put an app I am developing in the cloud without using a disk image or a zip file so that I could try it in another computer using another OS version. When I tried to run it on the other computer all executables turned into non-executables. Onde I did that and then I went back to my developer machine the crashes started to happen. I checked the signature and found out the certificate had been revoked.

Comment: I solved the problem by revoking the old certificate and create a new one. That's it. But if you @dfd and others think that's a no-no in SO then I won't post anything.

Comment: It may be worth inquiring on [Ask Different Meta](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/) if the question would be appropriate at that main site. According to the [What topics can I ask about here?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) section over there, code programming is off topic but things dealing with the system could be on topic.

Comment: @cpburnz Perhaps you're right, because your users could that to you too, but on the other hand developers should know about this and tell their users not to do what I did, but that would be cross-posting.

Comment: I honestlydon't know, as I've been here for only 3 months. I'm still learning what's Meta and not, still learning to do triage, etc. Don't take my opinion to be of any value. @jvarela, a question specific to your incident... would Test Flight have accomplished what you were trying to do? Or is that iOS only?

Comment: I decided to put a more elaborate explanation in my blog at http://macscheduler.net/blog/ I think this is the best option.

Comment: @Don'tPanic I also approve of your opinion. Does that count as a "consensus"?

Comment: @Cody Yes it does. (In my opinion.)

Comment: @jvarela if you do decide to add a self answer, there's nothing wrong with linking to your blog for more details, as long as you include enough info in the Q&A for it to be understandable without the linked material.

Comment: Ok, 16 comments and no answer. I'm really feeling I don't understand Meta well enough. @Cody, please, for me (and any other thick-headed well-meaning people)... what opinion do you prove of? I believe I can't do double "@" stuff, even on Meta. And yeah, if you were being sarcastic, please, say so.

Comment: @dfd "I'm really feeling I don't understand Meta well enough" - that's okay, meta is a big place :) Its a bit different from regular SO but one thing is very much the same: answers are not to be given quick, they are to be given correctly. That can take time. But sometimes people who live in comments need a tiny push to go ahead and post their perfectly fine answer as an answer ;)

Comment: "I was thinking to ask this question: Why suddenly all my apps did start to crash with an EXC_CRASH" – would it not be way too late at that point? An answer would then come down to "yeah sorry, nothing you can do anymore". I don't think (but hope I'm wrong) that an 'open' question "How to prevent Apple to (etc)" is appropriate for SO.

Comment: Everything Don't Panic said about how to write the Q&A but cpburnz is also right in that it would probably be safer to ask at Ask Different instead of here since this wasn't an issue with your code but with Apple's rules.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Since we are a question and answer site, if you want to share information here, the only appropriate way to do that is by adding an on-topic, answerable question with an answer.

While a Q&A on the issue you encountered may possibly be a good fit for another Stack Exchange site as well (I'm not sure because I usually just hang around here,) I think it meets [the on-topic guidelines in the help center.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) It certainly sounds like

> "a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development."

I'm not an Apple developer, but from what you've described it sounds like something that would be easy enough for another developer to encounter at some point, so an answer that explains what causes it and how to fix it could be a useful thing to have here.

If you decide to add a question and self-answer, keep in mind that the question should be able to stand on its own as a good question without depending on your answer. Because your question won't have much code, if any, it will be at risk of being perceived as too broad, or asking about a problem that is not reproducible and unverifiable. In order to avoid that and keep the question on-topic, you just need to be sure to include enough details for someone else to be able to reproduce the problem (not that they'd really want to.)

"Why are my apps crashing?" would obviously be too broad. "Why are my apps crashing with this specific error?" would probably still be too broad, as I assume there are other reasons for the "Code Signature Invalid" error, and good answers aren't guesses. But "Why are my apps crashing with this specific error after I did these specific things?" narrows down the question enough to make it answerable by someone like you who has dealt with that problem.

Your blog post was a nice write-up, and you could provide a link to it in your answer, but be sure to include enough information in the answer itself to fully answer the question without depending on anything external.

Comment: Thanks for your untiring input. I posted the question at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41771688/why-suddenly-did-all-my-apps-start-to-crash-with-an-exc-crash-code-signature-in/41771882#41771882

Comment: @jvarela You're welcome. Looks like the meta effect has been kind to you. :)